# .NETでIJCADの既定のファイル保存形式を取得したい

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD2019で以下のようにDWGファイルを保存するコードを作成しています。

```
using (var db = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database)
{
    DwgVersion dwgVer = db.OriginalFileVersion;
    db.SaveAs("TEST.dwg", dwgVer);
}
```

保存するDwgVersionを
[ツール]-[オプション]の「開く/保存」タブにある”名前を付けて保存のファイル形式”に
合わせた値で行いたいのですが呼び出す方法はあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoCADでは、DocumentCollection.DefaultFormatForSaveプロパティで、現在設定されている保存形式を取得できますが、IJCADの.NET APIには、DefaultFormatForSaveプロパティや、この値を扱うDocumentSaveFormat列挙体が実装されていないようです。

DefaultFormatForSaveプロパティはレジストリの値を取得しているだけなので、少し面倒ですがIJCADでも現在の保存形式の値を取得することはできるみたいです。

```
var ucm = Application.UserConfigurationManager;
var profile = ucm.OpenCurrentProfile();
var section = profile.OpenSubsection("General");
var format = section.ReadProperty("DefaultFormatForSave", 0);
```

取得した値の詳細は、AutodeskのヘルプのDocumentSaveFormat列挙体のページを確認してみてください。